# Why is SSL Negotiation intermittently slow or fast on this web site?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, lets-encrypt

**AUTHOR'S NOTE:** When I originally asked this question, it looked like the problem was due to SSL negotiation. But someone pointed out that the problem could simply be rate-limited connections or a transient network problem (or something similar). I tested their theory and they were right. The same problems happen WITHOUT SSL. I've made an update further in this question to indicate that.

I'm leaving the question title for documentation for future people that run into this issue. Though, at the present time, I still haven't solved the problem -- working on that and needing help.

---

**Original question (Update follows)**

I am testing the webpage https://www.diannahouxcoaching.com/contact using webpagetest.org.

I am getting intermittent performance problems with SSL Negotiation.

In one instance, Negotiation takes 49ms, but in another instance, it takes almost 3 whole seconds!

[image: Fast SSL Negotiation]

[image: Super slow SSL Negotiation]

*NOTE: Ignore the yellow highlighted row indicating a 301 issue. That is another problem being resolved seperately.*

You can see the enormous purple line on the initial request in the second image.  But the line is miniscule in the first image.  2852ms vs 49ms!

This behavior seems to be completely unpredictable, and can happen on any page and on any resource that initiates a full SSL Negotiation.

I have not been able to find any information on the internet about troubleshooting performance problems like this.

- I looked at Apache2 Access and Error logs and found nothing useful.
- I watched HTOP and see nothing unusual. CPU usage is less than 5% at all times, even during page requests.
- I checked https://www.diannahouxcoaching.com with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and I get an A rating. I see nothing strange anywhere in any of the details.

This is running on an Amazon EC2 Instance.
My server version is: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

I'm using Let's Encrypt via Certbot. Could this be related to the issue? I can't find any information even on webpagetest.org telling me if the SSL negotiation time is being affected by their test software's certification lookup. I'm left to guess that this problem is strictly caused by my server, but I really can't tell if that's even true.

Can anyone offer any insight?

---

**UPDATE - ITS NOT AN SSL PROBLEM**

I had to post about this on another forum to get any help. It was suggested that the problem looks like a connection rate-limiting issue or a transient network problem -- implying that it may have nothing to do with SSL. So I disabled SSL on my site and tested a vanilla HTTP connection.

Low and behold, the same massive delays happen on random resources. It's NOT being caused by SSL.  The waterfall test just made it *appear* that way.

Here's a sample of a non-encrypted HTTP test:
[image: HTTP Test with Slowness]

I've looked through my Apache modules to see if there is a rate-limiting module installed. I don't see anything of the sort.

If it's a network problem, I could potentially test that by migrating from an east coast data center to a west coast data center. But a data center migration seems a bit overkill if the problem might be the server config. I'm just not sure how to prove that its the server.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can prove whether its the server or a network delay?

Comment: There are two kinds of renegotiation. (1) A full negotiation lile the initial one, with certificate exchange and verify, pre-master secret computation, etc., and (2) re-key, using all other session attributes as-is. (1) happens when the session expires or is expired.

Comment: When you say "re-key", I presume you're talking about Resumption, in which the browser asks the server if its ok to make another request using previously agreed parameters.  My server passes Resumption checks.  It's also visible in the waterfall charts. You can see that most of the requests have zero SSL negotiation.  I'm having the problem on full negotiation requests.

Comment: No, I am not talking about resumption, I am talking about a new `ClientHello` in the middle of a session. This causes an abbreviated handshake and allocation of a new session key.

Comment: Ok. Can you please explain what bearing this has on the question?

Comment: I'm guessing you're suggesting that either a the full-negotiation or the re-key is causing an issue.  Either way, this intermittent range of 49ms to nearly 3000ms is clearly something wrong.  I need insight in how to figure out the cause of this problem.  This is a troubleshooting issue.